# FileHelper reading in CSV where initial row specifies column names

Tags: c#, filehelpers

For context I'm trying to parse in a 7dtd localization file.  The contents of the file looks something akin to this:

```
Key,File,Type,UsedInMainMenu,NoTranslate,english,Context / Alternate Text,german,latam,french,italian,japanese,koreana,polish,brazilian,russian,turkish,schinese,tchinese,spanish
meleeToolCrowbar,items,Tool,,,Crowbar,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

The problem is this, the order of the data presented varies from file to file, where the 1st row specifies the item placement for each entry further in the file.  I need to read in this file and merge it with multiple other files of similar construction.

I initially tried to just read in and use split string on comma to parse, but alas some of the fields may have commas in them (bounded by quotes).  So when I started investigating potential solutions FileHelpers came up.  However, from what I can tell this uses a static column to property definition, and that won't work for my context as a) order of the columns vary and b) not all columns are present.

Any help finding a solution would be much appreciated.

Comment: Read the file using a dedicated CSV library then; for example with CSVHelper you just define a class with the properties you want from the file, and then tell it to read the file. It doesn't matter the order of columns. Read this: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#reading-a-csv-file - don't reinvent a whell that doesn't need inventing (for the millionth time)

Comment: From what I see this isn't going to work either, as you define a property on a class and then associated the property with an entry in the column of the file.  This won't work as it's unknown exactly how many columns there are and what the order of the columns will be.

Comment: Straight up, I wouldn't have recommended it if I didn't think it was going to work. I've a project open in front of me right now that uses CSVH to read a file of half a million rows and 37 columns, but I only have interest in 7 of them. The C# properties don't even have he same name as the headers;most the headers have spaces, so attributes are used to map from eg the file's "Product Code" column to my ProdCode property

Answer (score 1):

If you review the dynamic [ClassBuilder](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_Dynamic_ClassBuilder.htm) part of the library, you can create a class that maps between the columns and the class you want by adding [fields](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/T_FileHelpers_Dynamic_DelimitedFieldBuilder.htm). Then use the [CreateRecordClass](https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/M_FileHelpers_Dynamic_ClassBuilder_CreateRecordClass.htm) object to create the actual class type to be used by the runtime engine.

You would need to parse the first row and then work out what columns you have.  I do believe that you can use the delimited engine to do this work for you if you don't specify any columns or types.

It's more complex with FileHelpers than with say CSVHelper where you create the mapping in a simple way.  If you use the CsvDataReader then you use [ClassMap](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/mapping-properties/)'s to go between your column headers and the properties, even specifying specific [indexes](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-multiple-record-types/) for the columns you actually want.

```
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        HasHeaderRecord = false,
    };
    using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<FooMap>();
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<BarMap>();
        var fooRecords = new List<Foo>();
        var barRecords = new List<Bar>();
        while (csv.Read())
        {
            switch (csv.GetField(0))
            {
                case "A":
                    fooRecords.Add(csv.GetRecord<Foo>());
                    break;
                case "B":
                    barRecords.Add(csv.GetRecord<Bar>());
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown record type.");
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public sealed class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(2);
    }
}

public sealed class BarMap : ClassMap<Bar>
{
    public BarMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(2);
    }
}
```